# Why transform has to be broadcasted periodically?

Tags: ros, sensor, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Nowadays I am trying to build a mobile robot with several sensors, and be curious about using relative positions of sensors in ROS.

In several tutorials, every transform(in my case, sensors) must be broadcasted periodically even if they are static in the whole robot configuration; Assuming that the base link and the relative position of sensors will not be changed.

Is there any specific reasons to this? I couldn't find any documents or explanation to this.
I think it is kinda waste of resources.

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235257/why-transform-has-to-be-broadcasted-periodically?/) by [Kay Park](https://answers.ros.org/users/26987/kay-park/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2016-05-26

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the original `tf` implementation you are correct; even transforms that don't change over time need to be constantly re-broadcast. This does indeed waste bandwidth and can lead to unnecessary exceptions being thrown. This was just a design oversight that was addressed with the release of [tf2](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2). `tf2` introduces the `tf_static` topic to fix exactly the issue you are describing. Many of the tutorials on the wiki are still using the `tf` API and functionality, and should likely be updated (remember, it is a wiki that supports community editing).

Further reading

- tf2 Migration guide: http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Migration
- tf2 wiki page: http://wiki.ros.org/tf2
- ROSCon presentation on tf2: http://www.osrfoundation.org/wordpress2/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/tf2.pdf

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kay Park](https://answers.ros.org/users/26987/kay-park/) on 2016-05-26**:
Thanks a lot for your detailed answer, appreciate it. :)